# Softkeyboard moves button in LinearLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, button, android-linearlayout, android-softkeyboard

Hi I'm designing a navigation application for as a Uni project. I'm having problems with getting the button to stay underneath the soft keyboard when it appears. I'm using LinearLayout as a frame. I've searched a lot and tried different techniques but nothing seems to work.

[a picture of the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q0QsH.png)

Here is my XML file:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0px"
        android:layout_height="0px"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true" />

    <requestFocus />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1.0"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/navi_searchfield1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="Current location" >
        </EditText>

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/navi_listview1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp">
        </ListView>

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/navi_searchfield2"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="Destination" />

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/navi_listview2"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
        </ListView>

    </LinearLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/start_navigation"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dip"
        android:background="@drawable/start"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:text="Start navigation" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"` to your activity in AndroidManifest.xml as:

```
    <activity
                android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
.
.
.                
    </activity>
```

This will prevent SoftKeyboard from moving your button, giving you an output like:
[image]

You can use the button even though the keyboard is shown by scrolling on the screen. But I think you probably can't show the keyboard above the button because I worked with SoftKeyboard and it uses:

```
  android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
```

So, you can only keep your layout safe from being pushed by SoftKeyboard.

Comment: Adding android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" didn't work neither did android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" or both together...

Comment: @PhilipMasek I said [Softkeyboard](http://pastebin.com/trhPZG1U) uses **android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"** that's why it keeps popping from bottom, you can't use android:layout_alignParentBottom without **RelativeLayout** . **android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"** just works perfect for me, I tried with your XML. You can try with following **XML** and **Manifest File** that worked for me.

[XML](http://pastebin.com/inepx8JK)

[Manifest](http://pastebin.com/HwZC5caP)

Comment: @PhilipMasek It worked perfectly for me, I'm giving you the complete sample project that worked, try running this one:[sampleroject](http://www.mediafire.com/?l9tg9874a7579l9)